# How can I search within .eml files using Spotlight?

Tags: macos, email, snow-leopard, spotlight

I tried searching for terms found on .eml files on my HD using Spotlight, but it never produces results. Is there a way to search within the content of .eml files using Spotlight?

Comment: Yes, I tested this by finding some .eml files, quick-looking them, then searching just in that directory for some terms that I saw in there.  Spotlight returns good results.  However, this is on 10.11.6, I don't know if it works in Snow Leopard.